# Подскажите как объединить несколько списков в json python

Tags: python, json, requests, beautiful-soup

Нужно соединить несколько списков в json
Имею списки с названием товара и с ценой
Делаю так:

```
lists = ['products1_name', 'products1_price']
data = {listname: globals()[listname] for listname in lists}
with open('abc.json', 'w', encoding='utf-8') as outfile:
    json.dump(data, outfile, indent=5, ensure_ascii=False)
```

Получаю список товаров и список цен.
Как сделать вот так:

```
товар1: [name: ******,
        price: *****]
товар2: [name: ******,
        price: *****]
```

Comment: Для соединения списков используйте ZIP. У меня есть видео, где объясняю как это делать: https://youtu.be/TjSoYCO-xig

Comment: Добавьте данных, чтоб был воспроизводимый пример. Списки по два-три элемента.